Windows 10 Update keeps failing (0x80070002) when installing KB5034441
When running Windows Update it says it encountered an error.
The message says:

There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again
later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact
support for information, this may help: (0x80070002)

When clicking button 'Retry' it tries to install KB5034441.
Clicking button 'View update history' it lists:

2024-01 Security Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems
(KB5034441) Failed to install on dd/MM/yyyy - 0x80070002


What you describe is a know issue with KB5034441. There is a known documented solution to the problem. Increase the size of the WinRE by at least 350MB and the patch will install without a problem.

0x80070643 is caused by the WinRE partition size. I can’t explain why you submitted 3 answers that didn’t even answer your question.

Tried to manually download via the Microsoft Update Catalog.
It is NOT listed:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5034441

This doesn’t answer your question. The patch is failing to install due to the size of your WinRE partition

You may want to hide the update as it does not seem available anymore.
I would not recommend hiding the update if you have encrypted the data on your disk (i.e. you have bitlocker enabled), the KB5034441 update will prevent a successful attacker to bypass the BitLocker Device Encryption feature on the system storage device.
To double check, start PowerShell as an admin and run the following commands:
Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "C:"

Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint "D:"

reagentc /info

Steps:

Download Microsoft tool 'Show or Hide Updates' (it seems the executable is not signed properly by Microsoft, your browser will ring the alarm bell).
Scan the dowloaded executable using Microsoft Defender to make sure it does not contain malware.
Run the tool and hide KB5034441.
Run Windows Update again. It now should say that 'You're up to date'.

Tool can be downloaded:

https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab


This doesn’t answer your question. The patch is failing to install due to the size of your WinRE partition

It’s really important to install KB5034441 if you have a WinRE partition, otherwise you are vulnerable, to a pretty severe vulnerability that cannot be patched.

Error code 0x80070002 commonly means that the file was previously downloaded but currently not found on disk:
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Tried to install the update manually:

Start PowerShell as admin.
Install module 'kbupdate'
Tried dowloading update 'KB5034441'

Result:

The update could NOT manually be downloaded.

Powershell commands:
Install-Module KBUpdate -Scope CurrentUser
Save-KbUpdate -Name KB5034441

More info:
https://github.com/potatoqualitee/kbupdate


This doesn’t answer your question. The patch is failing to install due to the size of your WinRE partition
